# Life metrics for v-brake pads (time to replace, time to change)

Tags: brakes, brake-pads

I ride my bikes quite frequently and need to use the brakes slightly harshly (because of the traffic light changes and cars at my front) as I approach some gradients worth 40 degrees downhill. My regular commute culminates to approximately 4 miles (with gradients and 5 days a week) and 0.25 miles (with gradients and 2 days a week). I have used simple tuning to maintain the v-brake positions along my front and rear rims and cable tensions for the brake cable (by adjusting the nuts near the brake levers). However, it seems that they don't stay put for more than a month or two. Additionally, I noticed this morning that my rear brake pads are almost worn out (broken and cracked edges). My question is, how do I determine how often the brake pads needs replacements? It would be fantastic if someone points suggests any side-effects such as brake cable wire damages and replacements etc.

Also, I recently puchased [this](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/lifeline-performance-v-brake-holders-inserts-4-pack/) set of pads with housings. Does anyone know if it is any good? My current brake pads are naked i.e. without any housings.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: before groove in the pad starts to disappear, you need to change the pads. As set of pad inserts for your pads is about 5 Euro, I would probably change them even more often.

Comment: The pads you bought are cartridge pads (i.e. the metal holder is permanent and you replace the rubber insert.) Housing is what your run your brake and derailleur cables through.

Comment: Brake pads generally degrade when they are used while heated. But for commuting a minimum of 1 year for the cheapest possible pads would be my bet!

Comment: @WTHarper       Okay I got the housing mixed with shoes (i.e. holder). But can I replace them with my current brakes? They are simply pads, no holders.

Comment: @Vorac         Thanks for the suggestion! Based on my statistics, replacing the pad every 3 months is okay? Also, is it okay to use some lubrication so that the friction (between rim and brake pad surface) is minimised?

Comment: No, Do not lubricate your brake pads or rims in any way whatsoever. The whole point is to maximize friction.  Not only that, but some lubricants might actually break down the rubber in the pads.

Comment: @user2030818 NO! Don't lubricate your rims for any reason ever! You want as much friction between the rim and the brake pads as possible.   If the new holder is compatible with your brakes (i.e. threaded post, smooth post, or what have you) it should be fine. Generally V Brakes use longer pads than traditional road brakes, so match the length of the pad as well.

Comment: Also, 3 months seems too frequent. I replace mine every 6 months or so and I ride quite a lot. Make sure you're cleaning your rims from time to time with some alcohol or other residue-free solvent.

Comment: After reading the last three comments from Kibbee and WTHarper, it seems that I need to clean the rims using normal wipes and let it dry off....

Comment: Just did the cleaning, used some simple stainless steel cleaner spray with normal clothes (1-2 sprays) and cleared all the dirt and oily bits from the rim :)

Comment: Make sure the cleaner doesn't have any oils in it to make the stainless shiny. If you rub your finger on the rim you shouldn't feel any oil at all. A safer bet is isopropyl or denatured alcohol (easy to find, inexpensive, no residue.)

Comment: In answer to your original question, you should replace your brake pads when they're getting close to worn out.  This is basically a matter of how much pad material is left -- you need to replace them before the metal holder is in any danger of scraping the rims -- could be months, could be years, depending on your use.  (Also, on very lightly used bikes, you need to replace the pads when they get dry and hard -- every 5-10 years or so.)

Comment: Note that there are usually different types of pad material available -- some "hard" and requiring more force to use, others "soft" and "grabby".  The harder pads generally will wear maybe 30-50% longer (though they will probably cause more rim wear).  A good shop will usually have 2-3 different types to choose from, in the popular sizes.

Comment: @DanielRHicks  Good to see your comments Daniel. Should I then look for "how" flat the brake pads have become? I mean when you buy them, you can see the edges and marks clearly on the brake pads. By regular use and friction, I believe they will worn out. Is it good way to identify when I should change them? Sorry, but I am simply using people's experience to guide myself :P

Comment: They will naturally wear flat from use, and that's not a problem.  Rather, it's the thickness -- if there are no wear indicators (bike shop people can show you if there are, and I think they're there on most newer pad designs) then you want to replace when, at its thinnest point, you have maybe 1/4" of pad to wear before the metal holder begins to rub the rim.  *Important:* The pad will almost always wear faster (*much* faster) in the rear (the "leading edge") of the pad, due to the forces on it during braking.  You need to check *both ends* of the pad (and the middle) when checking pad wear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to give a general estimate on how often brake pads should be replaced, as conditions vary. (Including how often you ride, temperature, humidity, do you store your bike in direct sunlight, how old the brakes are, etc.) If it looks worn, replace it.

Adjusting brake tension via the screw nuts on the handlebars is the best way to make adjustments. As brakes wear down with use, you will need to make these adjustments to compensate. Needing to do this ever month or two seems within the normal range for how often you use your bike.

Another factor to keep in mind is that cables will stretch with use. If the screw nuts on the handlebars are at their limit, you will need to loosen the nut holding the cable at the brake to adjust the cable. (When you make this adjustment, make sure to reset the screw nuts on the handlebar).

Your recently purchased brake pads seem fine. I've found that a manufacture will include the housing even if it's not needed. Just be sure to toe-in your brakes slightly, and reset the handlebar screw nuts (and cables) as needed.